# Second animation with @keywords does not apply to div

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm trying to create a progress bar, and what i basically do is trying to add 2 animations to 2 seperate progress bar divs. Here is the html:

```css
/* The animation frames start */


@keyframes progres1 {
    from {width: 0%;}
    to {width: 70%;}
};

@keyframes progres2 {
    from {width: 0%;}
    to {width: 90%;}
};

/* The css for containers start */

.progress-main-container{
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.progress-container{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.progress-container p{
    width: 20ch;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.progress-1, .progress-2, .progress-3{
    position: relative;
    height: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 20px 0 rgb(69 67 96 / 10%);
}


.progress-1 .color-1{
    position: absolute;
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #ff8a00, #e52e71);;
    width: 0px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    animation: progres1 1s linear;  
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}

.progress-2 .color-2{
    position: absolute;
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #ff8a00, #e52e71);;
    width: 0px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    animation: progres2 1s linear;  
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}

.progress-3 .color-3{
    position: absolute;
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #ff8a00, #e52e71);;
    width: 0px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    animation: progres1 1s linear;  
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}
```

```html
<div class="progress-main-container">
    <div class="progress-container">
        <p>Java</p>
        <p style="width: 5ch !important; font-weight: bold; font-size: 13px;">90%</p>
        <div class="progress-1">
            <div class="color-1"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="progress-container">
        <p>HTML/CSS</p>
        <p style="width: 5ch !important; font-weight: bold; font-size: 13px;">90%</p>
        <div class="progress-2">
            <div class="color-2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="progress-container">
        <p>React Native</p>
        <p style="width: 5ch !important; font-weight: bold; font-size: 13px;">90%</p>
        <div class="progress-3">
            <div class="color-3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see from the above css, im applying the animation to `.progress-x .color-x` classes, (x representing 1,2 and 3). Now the problem im facing here is that my 2nd progress bar, which is `.progress-2 .color-2` in css, where i have applied the `progres2` keyframe animation, which does not get applied. My first keyframe animation which is `progres1` gets applied to my first and last progress bars, but for some reason my second animation cannot animate my second progress bar.

Displays like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKVw5.png)

I did try applying my first animation keyframe with the second progress bar and it worked, for some reason my 2nd keyframe `progres2` does not work.

Here is the JS Fiddle link :

https://jsfiddle.net/Yeshanh/104t5mvb/5/

I hope someone can help me to apply my second keyframe animation to my second progress bar, cheers!

Comment: Remove `;` after `@keyframes` declaration.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have wrong `;`

```css
/* The animation frames start */


@keyframes progres1 {
    from {width: 0%;}
    to {width: 70%;}
}

@keyframes progres2 {
    from {width: 0%;}
    to {width: 90%;}
}

.progress-main-container{
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.progress-container{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.progress-container p{
    width: 20ch;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.progress-1, .progress-2, .progress-3{
    position: relative;
    height: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 20px 0 rgb(69 67 96 / 10%);
}


.progress-1 .color-1{
    position: absolute;
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #ff8a00, #e52e71);;
    width: 0px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    animation: progres1 1s linear;  
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}

.progress-2 .color-2{
    position: absolute;
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #ff8a00, #e52e71);;
    width: 0px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    animation: progres2 1s linear;  
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}

.progress-3 .color-3{
    position: absolute;
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #ff8a00, #e52e71);;
    width: 0px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    animation: progres1 1s linear;  
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}
```

```html
   <div class="progress-main-container">
                    <div class="progress-container">
                        <p>Java</p>
                        <p style="width: 5ch !important; font-weight: bold; font-size: 13px;">90%</p>
                        <div class="progress-1">
                            <div class="color-1"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="progress-container">
                        <p>HTML/CSS</p>
                        <p style="width: 5ch !important; font-weight: bold; font-size: 13px;">90%</p>
                        <div class="progress-2">
                            <div class="color-2"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="progress-container">
                        <p>React Native</p>
                        <p style="width: 5ch !important; font-weight: bold; font-size: 13px;">90%</p>
                        <div class="progress-3">
                            <div class="color-3"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: thnx dude @Evren

Comment: You are welcome :)